# Android - press key programmatically

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm developing an android application which uses w softkeyboard

What I want to do is to programmatically press a key on the keyboard

How can this be implemented?

Comment: What exactly are you asking??  A key press is input provided by the user.  Are you asking how to capture a key press programmatically?

Comment: I want to for example to change the keyboard layout programatically and this can be achieved by clicking on a key on the keyboard

Answer (score 3):

`Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent)` is your friend in this case. :)

Comment: This can only be used within your own activity.

Comment: how can i press backspace key using this method

Comment: ``KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL`` seems to be the key you're after.